# Loading MNIST dataset from Keras JS in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, keras, mnist

How to load MNIST dataset from KerasJS in Node?

I imported their header file

```
const KerasJS = require('keras-js')
var mnist = KerasJS.mnist
```

This gives no error, 
But whenever i try the load_data()

```
var x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = mnist.load_data()
```

It gives error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'load_data' of undefined
```

So what is the acceptable syntax to load MNIST dataset by KerasJS in Node?

I also can't find anything much on their documentation.

Comment: What error do you get? Check the discription of the package, it tells you how it's supposed to be used I think. https://www.npmjs.com/package/keras-js

Comment: Yes, i refered those too, they had used mnist dataset in python. I am hoping for a solution for importing mnist dataset in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

I found out another way to import mnist dataset in Nodejs,
instead of requiring Keras-js use mnist

```
var mnist = require("mnist");
var set = mnist.set(8000,2000);
var trainingSet = set.training;
var testSet = set.test;
```